# How to extract only paragraph part from a link excluding other links from a web page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to extract sentences from a web page, but I am unable to exclude other links or side icons presented in that web page.

I am trying to find all the occurrences of 'p' from a web page (meaning paragraph) but I am getting other results as well which are not required.

My Code:

```
  import re
  from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize, ngrams
  from collections import Counter
  from urllib import request
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  url = "https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nba/rockets/2019/01/25/james-harden-30-points-22-consecutive-games-rockets-edge-raptors/2684160002/"
  html = request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
  raw = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml") 


 partags = raw.find_all('p') #to extract only paragraphs 
 print(partags)
```

I am getting the following output (posting as an image because copying pasting will not look that tidy)

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGC1P.png

But I would like to extract only this kind of sentences from the link, is there any additional filter which I could apply.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlPUV.png'

```
Code after Valery's feedback.  

partags = raw.get_text()
print(partags)
```

Output which I am getting(it has links and others in JSON format as well)

```
This is just sample from the full output: 

James Harden extends 30-point streak, makes key defensive stop
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "NewsArticle",
    "headline": "James Harden extends 30-point streak, makes key defensive stop to help Rockets edge Raptors",
    "description": "James Harden scored 35 points for his 22nd consecutive game with at least 30, and forced Kawhi Leonard into a missed 3 at buzzer for 121-119 win.",
    "url": "https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nba/rockets/2019/01/25/james-harden-30-points-22-consecutive-games-rockets-edge-raptors/2684160002/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=amp&utm_campaign=speakable",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nba/rockets/2019/01/25/james-harden-30-points-22-consecutive-games-rockets-edge-raptors/2684160002/"
    },
```

Comment: it's also common to import bs4 as `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs`

Comment: @AmirhosImani isn't it going to give me same thing or am I missing something here?

Comment: it's the same thing...it's more common to import it as `bs` similar to how you import pandas as `pd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bs4 docs about this  [BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

response = requests.get("https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nba/rockets/2019/01/25/james-harden-30-points-22-consecutive-games-rockets-edge-raptors/2684160002/")
html = response.text
raw = bs(html, "html")

for partag in raw.find_all('p'):

    print(partag.get_text())
```

Here is [**Link to results**](https://telegra.ph/bs4-get-text-results-01-27)

So calling get_text() on partags (paragraph tags) produces valid text without noise.

Comment: Thanks @valery, I was looking at  this link but does not seem to handle all the cases, I am still getting links.                                                                             
partags = raw.get_text()
print(partags)

Comment: It's interesting. Could you provide example of pastable html (not image) to test?

Comment: Thank You and I have added the output which I am getting from Get_text in my question above.

Comment: Added full example how to use get_text() to extract text from p tags

Comment: Thank You for the help and solution, I am getting expected output.